# Regex: Exclude replacing matches based on prefixes

Tags: javascript, regex

Note: I'm using JavaScript in the case that changes the proposed solutions.

When looking through multiple files and changing a property/parameter like the word "count" (e.g. `count`, `register.count`, `function(count)`, `getCount`, `incrementCount`) I run into a issue of changing a word like "discount", "recount", or "encounter".

I realize that for my small use case* this error can be avoided by using simple heuristic - looking for known character groupings that prefix "count" and excluding them from replacement.

**Question**

**Is there any way to use a regular expression to look for all instances 
of "count" but ignore replacing if known prefix grouping of characters are found?**

Just to clarify*

I know my "prefix heuristic" breaks down if you tried to generalize for other words besides "count" in a large unknown search space but it'll suffice for now.

Comment: See http://javascript.info/tutorial/word-boundary

Comment: `.replace(/\bcount\b/g, something)`

Comment: But would boundaries break down on cases like ```getCount```?

Comment: No, but it would do a replace on register.count

Comment: Im having a hard time seeing how ```\b``` will able to distinguish between an okay prefix like "get" but know to skip one like "dis" unless my dashes to denote prefixes is confusing.

Comment: If `count` appears as part of another word, as in `getCount`, will the `C` always be upper-case? Can there also be additional characters immediately after `count`, such as `countItems`, and in that case will the first such character always be capitalized?

Comment: @NickPineda what are your approved and not approved prefixes?

Comment: @AndreasDM "get" and "increment" would be an example of ones we would allow. "dis", "re" and "en" would be cases we'd like to ignore because we know for our case they wouldn't be refering to the "count" property/parameter in our files.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the regex this way:

```
\b(get)?(count|Count)\b
```

You should apply the case insensitive switch.

```
\b assert position at a word boundary (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)
1st Capturing group (get)?
    Quantifier: ? Between zero and one time, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    Note: A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data
    get matches the characters get literally (case sensitive)
2nd Capturing group (count|Count)
    1st Alternative: count
        count matches the characters count literally (case sensitive)
    2nd Alternative: Count
        Count matches the characters Count literally (case sensitive)
\b assert position at a word boundary (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it's possible to go the exclusion route, given the lack of lookbehinds in javascript.

Wouldn't it be easier anyway for your "known" prefixes be the ones that are *allowed*? You cannot, after all, list every single regular word that has "count" somewhere in it. Allow for your known legal prefixes, and let `\b` take care of the rest:

- pattern: `(get|increment)count|\bcount\b //case insensitive`
- replace: `$1FOO`

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/bI0cF5/3)

Comment: using my question text as a demo was sooo clever! haha

Comment: Yours and @RudyTheHunter examples of using inclusion instead of exclusive sets work but it would be a lot harder. The amt of cases it's used is far greater then the few cases it should be skipped.